# Using Ubuntu Nautilus (File Manager), how do I get proper context menu items in list view?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, nautilus, files, filesystem

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and Gnome Files (Nautilus) v3.36.3-stable.

I prefer the Ubuntu Files to display my files in a List View (with file details) instead of the icon view.

However, when I want to right-click and get the context menu that shows more than the items for a specific file, I have to switch to Icon view so I can click "between" the files.

**File-specific Context Menu**

Here's a snapshot of the context menu I get in List View.  This is the context menu related to the specific file (and has some missing items).

[image: Ubuntu files context menu]

**Folder-Specific Context menu**

What I'm wondering, is how do I get the folder-specific context menu without having to switch back to icon view each time.  The only way I've found to get to the folder specific menu is to :

**1**. switch to icon view

**2**. click "between" the files

[image: folder-specific context menu]

Are there other ways to get this (2nd menu shown) menu to show up?

Comment: That is the answer. Thanks very much, tried searching but couldn’t find that.